# ForLoop to flip every third element in array of logical values (1 and 0)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

Let's say I have an array 1 x N of 1 and 0 values. Using for loop I am trying to flip every third value of the array. How would I go about this?

An example of what I would like to achieve

```
 V = [1 0 1 0 0 1]

 V = [1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
V(3:3:end) = ~V(3:3:end);
```

??

It doesn't use a `for` loop at all and I dare say it's faster.  This slices through your array, accessing every third element and inverting the values using the not / `~` operator.

However, if you insist on a loop, do something like this:

```
for ii = 3 : 3 : numel(V)
    V(ii) = ~V(ii);
end
```

Every third element that is non-zero becomes zero and vice-versa.

Comment: May I ask what does " ii " do?

Comment: `ii` is the loop counter.  At each iteration, `ii` changes from 3, 6, 9, up to as many values as you have in `V`.

Comment: What part of the loop is flipping the value of 1 or 0?

Comment: @kal the `~` operator does. It does an inversion. I suggest you read a MATLAB tutorial before asking any more questions.